# Show that $[X,Y]=0$ for all $Y$ a vector field of $M$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ a differentiable manifold and $X$ a vector field on $M$ such that $X(f)=0$ for all $f \in \mathcal C^{\infty}(U,\mathbb R)$ with $U$ an open set of $M$.

Show that for all vector field $Y$ on $M$, the Lie brackets $[X,Y]=0$ on $U$.

$[X,Y]=XY(f)-YX(f)=XY(f)$

$f\in \mathcal C^{\infty}(U,\mathbb R)$ so $Y(f) \in \mathcal C^{\infty}(U,\mathbb R)$
hence $X(Y(f))=0$.
Is my attempt true?

Comment: What is $U$ in your question? Actually, what is your question?

Comment: Lie brackets have a local behaviour. The fact that $U$ is not the whole manifold does not allow you to conclude that $[X,Y]=0$ in the whole manifold. You can easily construct a couunterexample to this with bump functions

Comment: Thanks you. I edit it.